# How to store reoccuring events in optimized way

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make booking system something like booking futsal ground. Here, the user can select the time and date and make the book for it, and they can also check for repetition like, daily, weekly, monthly until xx date. 
This means there will be end-date predefined.

So far I have come to the following model after quite some searching:

```
Events_repeat
--------------------
id
repeat_interval    `1 = daily, 2 = weekly, 3 = monthly`
repeat_date       `this is exactly the date something like 14th of every month`
ordinal        `1 = first, 2 = second, 3 = third, 4 =fourth, 5 = last`
week_days      `1 =  Sunday, 2 =  Monday,  4 = Tuesday, 8 = Wed, 16 = Thu, 32 = Fri, 64 = Sat`
start_date    `start date`
end_date    `end_date`
event_id        `foreign key`
```

So some examples:

```
id repeat_interval repeat_date ordinal week_days start_date end_date   
 1               1 NULL        NULL    NULL      2019-05-17 2019-07-17 -- a daily event
 2               2 NULL        NULL           33 2019-05-17 2019-07-17 -- a twice weekly event
 3               3          15 NULL    NULL      2019-05-17 2019-07-17 -- occurs at 15th of each month
 4               3 NULL              3        32 2019-05-17 2019-07-17 -- occurs at third Friday of each month
```

So, far I am convinced about storing strategy, but I am not convinced yet with its selecting strategy. I could not figure out it yet.

*Question:*
1) How can I fetch all the events that are going to happen in a particular month lets say at june of 2019
2) Or is there any other better way to handle task like this? Any package or library that do the task for me.

Comment: You have `start_date` and `end_date` which will be enough to get data, isn't it?

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Events_repeat a INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.event_id=b.id
WHERE (a.start_date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30')`

Comment: @JimishGamit Actually, that can also pick up events that occur either side of the specific time frame.

Comment: @JimishGamit specially how to figure it out which day it is, thats might be the main issue here. I am thinking about storing json_encode array instead

Comment: Yes, you can save dates on which event are going to occur on next dates. But what if they are repetitively for a year or may be long?  I  would suggest to run a cronjob which will keep updating those dates. this will help you to make your event module lighter while creating or updating